# Rails 5 stylesheet_link_tag adds application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to try out Ruby on Rails (version 5) for a project.

When I add `stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` to my layout, the application.js file is loaded.

The application.js file by default includes jquery which isn't available in my project currently, so an exception is thrown.

I could change the js file to stop the error.

Why is the stylesheet helper loading the js file?
Is this not the job of `javascript_include_tag`?

### Update

-- 30/07/2016 20:37 --
Solution
Ok it seems this happens due to all app/assets being processed when the stylesheet and/or javascript helper is used, so they both must be valid. However only the relevant files are included in the page.

Comment: do you have a `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include the `javascript_include_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag` the app/assets are all processed, so all must be valid.

The end result will still be that only the files you expect to be included in the webpage will be.